# Using markdown in JavaScript template engine

Tags: javascript, markdown, template-engine

How to use markdown(or any other markup -> HTML language) in a template. Is it possible with available JavaScript template engines?

Template:

```
This is a *sample* question?
![some_image](image/path)
{{screenshot}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Run first your template engine.
- Pass the rendered HTML to the markdown parser.
- Run your markdown parser.

I leave you a snippet that uses [Mustache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache) as template engine and the JavaScript implementation of [CommonMark](https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark.js/) for Markdown.

In the links above you can find the code that I used for the example.

```js
function loadUser() {
  var template = $('#template').html();
  var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {
    name: "*Luke*"
  });
  $('#target').html(rendered);

  var reader = new commonmark.Parser();
  var writer = new commonmark.HtmlRenderer();
  var parsed = reader.parse($('#target').html());
  var result = writer.render(parsed);
  $('#target').html(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/commonmark/0.28.1/commonmark.min.js"></script>

<body onload="loadUser()">
  <div id="target">Loading...</div>
  <script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
This is an example of **markdown** in a *template*.  
Hello {{ name }}!
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: this is the reasonable way of doing this in a two step process but i guess this feature should have been implemented builtin or via plugins  for common JS template engines.

Comment: Maybe some templates have actually a Markdown plugin, but the good thing about doing the two steps is the freedom to work with your Markdown parser  of choice.

Comment: totally agreed using this approach you have the freedom of choosing your markdown parser and Template engine. Actually i want to go with `EJS` and `marked` instead of `Mustache` and `commonMark`. Any comment on this combo?

Comment: I like Marked but have no experience with EJS. I think the only important thing is to ensure that the template tag delimiters (e.g. `{{...}}`) of your engine are not valid Markdown. That is, don't use things like `[...]` as delimiters.